# Want to display a photo in the cell of day in Calendar

Tags: java, android

I would like to display a photo in cells of days in Calendar. I am new in android app development. I have looked at Calendar class, but didn't find function where I cad add photo.

Something like this should look like.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

this [custom android calendar](https://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/) could help you with your problem. Basically the standard calendar can't do what you want so you have to modify the calendar/create an own calendar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CustomCalendarView](https://github.com/npanigrahy/Custom-Calendar-View)

```
<com.stacktips.view.CustomCalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendar_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/off_white"
        app:calendarBackgroundColor="@color/off_white"
        app:calendarTitleTextColor="@color/black"
        app:currentDayOfMonthColor="@color/blue"
        app:dayOfMonthTextColor="@color/black"
        app:dayOfWeekTextColor="@color/black"
        app:disabledDayBackgroundColor="@color/off_white"
        app:disabledDayTextColor="@color/grey"
        app:selectedDayBackgroundColor="@color/blue"
        app:titleLayoutBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:weekLayoutBackgroundColor="@color/white">
</com.stacktips.view.CustomCalendarView>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: thats pretty nice but can you add pictures or drawables too? that's what OP asked for and I'm interested too since I might start an android project where this would come in handy.

Comment: did you check link ??

Comment: I just flew over it and read a lot about decorators and customization but mostly I saw and read colors on the front page. I will read it again